# How to create and configure the relationship between entities in Xcode 14 without graphical mode editor style

Tags: xcode, core-data, data-modeling, entity-relationship

I have tried to search for options on how to create the relationship between entities and how to configure it in Xcode 14. However, I could not figure it out, if you can advise. Within the learning material the sources are still referring to methods using graphical mode editor style that is not available any more in Xcode 14 as have confirmed also at https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the Core Data model and select an entity, you will see its relationships in the editor. There is an add button below the list of relationships to add a relationship.

[image]